# Opencart: maintenance mode variable

Tags: opencart

When I set opencart to maintenace mode I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getLayout() on a non-object in
../catalog/controller/common/header.php on line 195
```

The code at line 195 is:

```
 $layout_id = $this->model_design_layout->getLayout($route);
```

I want to ignore this line when the site is in `maintenance mode`, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the line

```
$this->load->model('design/layout');
```

before the one giving an error in `catalog/controller/common/header.php` should correct this. If it doesn't, then try re-uploading `/catalog/model/design/layout.php`

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue is that one or more of your library files are corrupt from uploading. Re upload your `system/library/` folder from your local one. Your config files seem fine and the error doesn't reference a config issue.

Also what version are you using. Do you have vQMod? What PHP version is the server? As far as I know I think your line has been replaced. My OpenCart has not got that line. I use the latest version `1.5.5.1`